# VB.net One sub for many events

Tags: vb.net, function, events

I'm working on a function in VB.Net where a user can select a supplier from a list.

The idea is that the user will filter the list until the right supplier is visible in a datagridview

the user can then either double click on the row header, the cell content or select a supplier and then click an OK button

I am wondering though, how do I avoid building one Sub for each of the above three events, Can I create one sub that catches all three events?

```
Private Sub supplierSearchOkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles supplierSearchOkButton.Click
    initiativeForm.supplierConcatTextBox.Text = supplierSearchDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub supplierSearchDataGridView_CellContentDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles supplierSearchDataGridView.CellContentDoubleClick
    initiativeForm.supplierConcatTextBox.Text = supplierSearchDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub supplierSearchDataGridView_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles supplierSearchDataGridView.RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick
    initiativeForm.supplierConcatTextBox.Text = supplierSearchDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: They're all different types of events so you can't avoid having separate handlers for them. But there's nothing stopping you making another Sub and have them all calling that same Sub, if you want them to basically do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would go with the extra method option mentioned in the comments but, if you want to, you should be able to do this:

```vb
Private Sub SetSupplier(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles supplierSearchOkButton.Click,
                                                                  supplierSearchDataGridView.CellContentDoubleClick,
                                                                  supplierSearchDataGridView.RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick
    initiativeForm.supplierConcatTextBox.Text = supplierSearchDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

or even this:

```vb
Private Sub SetSupplier() Handles supplierSearchOkButton.Click,
                                  supplierSearchDataGridView.CellContentDoubleClick,
                                  supplierSearchDataGridView.RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick
    initiativeForm.supplierConcatTextBox.Text = supplierSearchDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

If you're not using any properties of the other `e` parameters then you can use the most general `EventArgs` for all three events and if you're not using the parameters at all then you can ditch them altogether. I didn't test this specifically but I'm fairly sure both will work.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to suggest, having already done so, this way works without problem.

Comment: For example, the Control.Click event handler passes an `EventArgs` object. But it's actually a `MouseEventArgs` object, so you can cast it and use it as such.

Comment: @Jimi, I wasn't aware of that. I suspect that it wasn't originally (`MouseEventArgs` itself wasn't added until .NET 1.1) but, when they added the `MouseClick` event in .NET 2.0, they decided to use the same `MouseEventArgs` object for both events.

Comment: Exactly that. There's also [a comment about it](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,13517) in the .Net Reference Source. It also applies to DoubleClick.

Comment: @Jimi, that's weird. I checked that source and they are actually creating a new `MouseEventArgs` object for each event. I could understand if they were using the same object but I can't really see why they would create a more complex object for the `Click` event when it wasn't even supposed to be used.

Comment: Those are the WndProc message handlers (MFC style), that's where the EventArgs-derived objects are generated. See the [WM_PAINT handler](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,13734) (the PaintEventArgs generator).